# How to configure collections other than fs.files fs.chunks in GridFsTemplate in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

GridFsTemplate insertes data in collections:fs.files and fs.chunks.
Is there any way to make GridFsTemplate use my own collections?

e.g. In my project, I need to dump all files in attachments.files and attachments.chunks.

I am able to do it using just GridFs like this:

```
DB mongoDB = mongoDbFactory.getDb();
GridFS fileStore = new GridFS(mongoDB, "attachment");
```

but I would like to do it by @autowire GridFsTemplate, perform operations like *gridFsTemplate.store(file, filename)*, and it should dump data in my own collections.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to Autowire it with a default Bucket, you can define a Bean for it in Mongo Client Configuration. It goes something like this:

Create a configuration class->

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConnectionConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    //store this in application.properties file 'mongo.file-system-bucket.attachment=attachment'
    @Value("${mongo.file-system-bucket.attachment}")
    private String bucketAttachment;

    //store this in application.properties file 'mongo.file-system-bucket.image=image'
    @Value("${mongo.file-system-bucket.image}")
    private String bucketImage;

    @Autowired
    private MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter;

    @Bean(name = "gridFsTemplateAttachments")
    public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mongoConverter, bucketAttachment);
    }

    @Bean(name = "gridFsTemplateImages")
    public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mongoConverter, bucketImage);
    }
}
```

Now to use these Beans you can Autowire them in your DAO and work with  different buckets as per your requirements.

Eg. ->

```
@Repository
public class AssetTransactionsDAO implements AssetTransactionsInterface {
    
    @Autowired
    private GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplateImages;

    @Autowired
    private GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplateAttachments;

    @Override
    public String insertAttachment(AttachementModel attachment){
     //do your stuff gridFsTemplateAttachments.store(.....)
        return "";
    }
}
```